# Java IDE for working over Remote Desktop

Tags: java, ide, remote-desktop

I have recently found out that anything Swing(NetBeans, IDEA) is excruciatingly slow to paint the UI over Remote Desktop(RDP).

Can you guys give me any suggestion for something that will work properly over RDP?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use Git, clone the repo to your local box, make changes, then commit?  I don't see any benefit to using RDP to develop; it'd slow you down considerably more than help.

Comment: Do not assume please. Anyway, when I'm at work, I like to connect to the home box and do something productive given free time. Hence - RDP. So currently the benefit of RDP is limited functionality instead of NO fuctionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, contrary to everything I've seen - mostly the **"Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"**, which is mentioned in a number of places, it is actually setting it to false that fixed the drawing issues(for me at least).  Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

RDP is optimized for native Windows apps and, regrettably, newer versions of RCP (like Vista/Win7's default RDP) is even *more* hostile to non-native apps than older (XP/Server 2003) versions.  Here's a good link:

- http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/280673
- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4204845

One workaround is to get a screaming fast CPU/graphics board, tons and tons of memory and a super high-speed network connection :)

Another is to:

- Select "32-bit true color" in your Terminal Services settings
- Select "Modem"
- Reduce screen resolution (heck, use 1024x768 if possible)

Here are some additional tips:

- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/04/remote-desktop-tips-and-tricks.html
- Try setting "Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1129187.html

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Solving-DIRECT-DRAW-ddraw-problems-in-Java-Swing-730.php

Comment: PS: for remote access, I've used many many things over the years: pcAnywhere, Remote Desktop and/or VNC over VPN; VNC over SSH; NetMeeting, Webex and LogMeIn over the web, etc etc .... and my current favorite for general remote access is *definitely* [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com).  The *free* version of LogMeIn :)  IMHO...

Comment: Actually, contrary to everything I've seen - mostly the "Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true", which is mentioned in a number of places, it is actually setting it to false that fixed the drawing issues. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

I am launching a java swing application from Linux, and display it as a Windows frame thanks to MobaXterm.

If you haven't done it already, please have a look at the following documentation :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html

Using `-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true` did not fixed my issue, but setting `xrender` to `true` did.

So here's the code I used on Linux :

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true'
java -jar my_java_application.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not only Swing that paints slow over Remote Desktop. However, Eclipse is based on SWT, based on native widgets, so it is not Swing.

Answer (score 0):

You should give [JavaWIDE](http://javawide.org/index.php/Main_Page) a try. It is an IDE designed for access to a JDK without it installed on a system, with a built-in storage system so you just need access to the internet. It's not exactly a program for accessing everything on the computer but it will do a good job with your programming. It may take a while however, as the compiling is done on a separate server.